# What is the special significance of the term ' signs' in relation to the miracles of Jesus?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-john, miracles

We read in Jn 6:26:
Jesus answered, “Very truly I tell you, you are looking for me, not because you saw the signs I performed but because you ate the loaves and had your fill.

```
                    Elsewhere also, John uses the term ' sign' while reporting the miracles of Jesus. In fact, we seldom here Jesus referring to his own deeds as miracles, one exception being Mtt 11:23:
```

And you, Capernaum, will you be lifted to the heavens? No, you will go down to Hades. For if the miracles that were performed in you had been performed in Sodom, it would have remained to this day.

```
                         My question therefore is: What  is the special significance of the term ' signs' in relation to the miracles of Jesus ?
```

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix the formatting. You can't put lots of spaces at the beginning of a line, or else it thinks you're writing code.

Comment: Thanks, curiousdannii. Of late, I have been using my Android- run phone  to post questions. It does not give much scope for formating.

Comment: For the definition and meaning of _semaion_ I would have thought SE-BH would be the place, myself.

Answer (score 3):

The Greek word for 'signs' is '*semeion* - a sign; mark; or signal'. It is the word from which our English semaphore is derived, indicative of signs made with flags over some distance. It is a form of sign language. Another form of sign language enables deaf people to know what words other people are speaking.

Miracles and wonders are not the same thing as 'signs', being far more excessive in description.

A sign is not the thing signified. It is not the reality: it is an allegory.  It is not the substance: it is a visionary shadow.

'Miracle' (as an act of power) is *'dunamis'*

However, if a sign points to something actual and greater than the sign itself, then **the miracles of Jesus in those two verses need to be understood as actual events Jesus performed, so as to point to himself as the Son of God, the promised Messiah.**

Comment: _A sign is not the thing signified. It is not the reality: it is an allegory. It is not the substance: it is a visionary shadow._ Up-voted +1.

Comment: Thanks, Anne.  John , for instance says: " What Jesus did here in Cana of Galilee was the first of the signs through which he revealed his glory; and his disciples believed in him."  My doubt is : Did the ' sign'  of Cana lead to a greater sign ? Suppose Jesus did not oblige Mary . Would it have an impact on his Ministry ? The wedding and the miracle are not referred to in retrospect in any of the Gospels , unlike the case of multiplication of bread which Jesus himself refers to at a later stage. So, in what way does the miracle at Cana serve as a ' sign'  ?

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan  It's speculation to wonder what might have resulted from Jesus not doing that sign at Cana. His ministry had to start at some point in time, and to start with signs pointing to him as the Messiah of miracles. The first sign was seeing Nathaniel under the fig-tree; enough of a sign to convince Nathaniel that Jesus was the Son of God (Jn.1:43-50.) Three days later came the wedding at Cana with that miracle. One sign is enough for some. Others won't believe no matter how many signs and miracles are given. (I still can't read all of your question.)

Comment: Seeing Nathaniel under the tree was a private sign to just a few who Jesus was calling to be disciples, and it was enough for Nathaniel. John adds in 2:11 that Cana was 'the beginning of miracles' causing his disciples to believe on him. It was a public display showing who he was. The private sign earlier had already convinced Nathaniel, so it would be the others who believed at Cana. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Anne. I stand enlightened